# The meaning of this equation

Tags: fuzzy-set

I've read a paper [Obstacle Avoidance Approaches for Autonomous
Underwater Vehicle](https://sci-hub.se/10.1109/JOE.2015.2506204) and I found the equation like :

$$
\alpha = \max_i \min_k \left(R \triangleleft R^T \right)_{ik}
$$

if the inside of "()" is a matrix, does anyone know the meaning of  the equations above ? I still confused on maximink terms.